# Does beer expiration change based on yeasts?

Tags: storage, aging, yeast

Part of my job involves selling beer. I was told by a coworker that visible yeast particulates at the top of a beer bottle indicate that it's not fit for consumption, whereas yeast at the bottom is fine.

Is this true? And if so, does it change depending on whether it's a top-fermenting or bottom-fermenting beer? Does this affect meads and ciders as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer no. The yeast used should have very little effect on on the expiry date. Things that will affect this more are:

- Temperature of fermentation
- Hot side aeration
- Cold side aeration
- Pasteurization
- Filtration
- Colour of bottle the beer is stored in
- Type of beer ie % dark malts
- Live product vs sterile filtered

This list is incomplete. This is an incredibly complex subject, there are PhDs in Brewing/Chemistry handed out for small aspects of each of these topics.

Here is a quick overview presentation of the technical aspects surrounding beer stability and stabilisation.

https://www.craftbrewersconference.com/wp-content/uploads/2015_presentations/F1420_Deniz_Bilge.pdf

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply! Any thoughts re: the statement on visible yeast particulates?

Comment: Visibility of yeast particulates have no affect on weather or not the beer is fit for consumption. Some yeasts do not flocculate (clump) in the same way as others, but a hazy or yeasty beer can be delicious and is almost certainly fit for consumption, unless it smells or tastes 'bad'.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot more sense to me, particularly given that I know some beers optimize for yeastiness (Hefeweizen). Great answer!

Comment: And some yeasts are naturally "top-fermenting" while others are not. A bottle of beer with yeast in it generally keeps longer and continues to (slightly) change in flavor is it ages.  In regards to the "colour of the bottle" - light/sunlight is the #1 factor is a beer going "skunky."  Clear is the worst, green is also not great. The trendy practice of adding a lime to a Corona started because it was needed to choke down that crappy, cheap, skunky beer.